# Locate and compare the most recent 02 files

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to compare the most recent 02 files that is located in the same folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "most recent"? most recently modified? most recently created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

diff_latest(){ 
  local file latest second
  for file in "${1:-.}"/*; do
    [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && second="$latest" && latest="$file"
  done  
  diff "$latest" "$second"
}
```

#### Usage

```
diff_latest /path/to/some/dir
```

Comment: Thanks.. just got the answer that I need with                    diff `ls -r | head -n +2`

Comment: @Mich what do you mean "my bad"? It was a good question! And if you like my answer, please accept it by clicking the check mark. Thanks

Comment: @Mich you can use `ls -c | head -2` if you want to **manually** observe the results. But please do not try to use this output in a programmatic way as parsing `ls` **[is chalk full of problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)**

Comment: I'm new to tech stuff and Stackoverflow.  "my bad" is a typo.   Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Zsh`](http://www.zsh.org/):

```
% diff *(.om[1,2])
```

[Explanation.](https://superuser.com/a/378144/37904)